# Open angular-ui-bootstrap accordion based on ID

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an accordion:

```
<accordion>
 <accordion-group  ng-repeat="group in groups" heading="{{group.title}}" id="{{group.id}}" is-open="group.open">
   <table class="table">            
       <tr>
         <td>{{group.definition}}</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
 </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

and each accordion has a unique ID.

I know how to open an accordion based on its position:

```
 <button ng-click="groups[0].open = !groups[0].open">Toggle Title 1 based on index</button>
```

but how do I open an accordion based on its ID?

My current attempt is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/c3GeaWfOgZ2YoQb2kUbW

Comment: You don't. It's all controlled by the `is-open` binding.

Comment: @Phil, how can I bind an ID (or something unique) to is-open? I'm looking for something like:`is-open="{{group.id}}.open"`

Comment: I'd use a map or something, eg `$scope.openGroups = {}` and `is-open="openGroups[group.id]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from my comment, try something like this...

In your controller, create a map to store open group information

```
$scope.accordionGroups = {};
```

If you want one group to default open, try this

```
$scope.accordionGroups[groups[0].id] = true;
```

Then use this in your template

```
<accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groups"
    heading="{{group.title}}" id="{{group.id}}"
    is-open="accordionGroups[group.id]">
```

To toggle a group with your button, use this

```
<button ng-click="accordionGroups.title1 = !accordionGroups.title1">Toggle title1</button>
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/scgOlYmOWTg45w2cxmRr?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: @rlsaj another option would have been to create a controller function to search for the group by ID in the array and set its `open` property to `true` but I feel like this is simpler