# 'Invalid left-hand side in assignment' error when using the NOT(!) operator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, logical-operators

I'm using this function:

```
$scope.myFunction = function(indexParent, childrenLength) {

    // close all inner accordion tabs
     for(i=0; i < childrenLength; i++) {
       !$scope.lettersandnumbers[indexParent].things[i].open = $scope.lettersandnumbers[indexParent].things[i].open;
     }

    // toggle parent tab
    $scope.lettersandnumbers[indexParent].open = !$scope.lettersandnumbers[indexParent].open;

 }
```

Here: `<button ng-click="myFunction(0, 3)">Toggle a</button>`
However the 'close all inner accordion tabs' section is giving me the Invalid left-hand side in assignment error. How can I alter the code to make it work?

https://plnkr.co/edit/TlKhBZer1wYMW0XXBcqO?p=preview

Many Thanks

**UPDATE**

answer with a few amendments: https://plnkr.co/edit/aMD5rGxpe48lziTb6xPk?p=preview

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `!` there?

Comment: i'm using the code in this question as a reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290429/open-angular-ui-bootstrap-accordion-based-on-id . (.open is false by default - closed ) so adding a ! will make the section open. I'm trying to close all inner tabs when another button is clicked.

Comment: Your comment says "close all inner accordion tabs"; if that's the case, wouldn't setting `open` to `false` be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like

```
$scope.myFunction = function(indexParent, childrenLength) {

    // close all inner accordion tabs
     for(i=0; i < childrenLength; i++) {
       $scope.lettersandnumbers[indexParent].things[i].open = !$scope.lettersandnumbers[indexParent].things[i].open;
     }

    // toggle parent tab
    $scope.lettersandnumbers[indexParent].open = !$scope.lettersandnumbers[indexParent].open;

 }
```

The `!` was on the left side of an assigment

**EDIT:**

Proof you cant use `!` on the left side:

```js
var a = true;
console.log(a);
!a = a;
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
$scope.myFunction = function(indexParent, childrenLength) {

  // First close the outer tab
   $scope.lettersandnumbers[indexParent].open = !$scope.lettersandnumbers[indexParent].open;

  // Close all inner tabs if the outer tab is closed
  for(i=0; i < childrenLength; i++) {
    $scope.lettersandnumbers[indexParent].things[i].open = !$scope.lettersandnumbers[indexParent].open ? false : $scope.lettersandnumbers[indexParent].things[i].open;
  }
}
```

Here I'm using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to determine if the inner tabs should be closed or not.

I've seen in your code that `myFunction` is called only on a button, you should find your way to make it work when you click an outer accordion

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I need the ! to be on the left side as I'm trying to turn !$scope.lettersandnumbers[indexParent].things[i].open into its just $scope.lettersandnumbers[indexParent].things[i].open

Comment: You can't use it on the left side. You are trying to alternate the boolean value. I get it. But you must use it on the right side

Comment: I understand. But if i use it on the right side this causes all the inner tabs to open when the button is clicked. '.open' is set to false by default. Is there another way I can alternate the boolean value instead of using '!'? Something like ($scope.lettersandnumbers[indexParent].things[i].open == true) = $scope.lettersandnumbers[indexParent].things[i].open, i'm not sure about the correct syntax

Comment: Ok, so your objective is to close all the inner accordion when you close the outer accordion?

Comment: Correct, i'm trying to close any inner tabs that may be open whenever any outer accordion tab is clicked.

Comment: Brilliant! this is what I needed. I'll put the final code in my question with a few minor tweaks. Thanks so much for your help.